# Add validation to vue-form-wizard

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm trying to add validation for an input field with vue-form-wizard.

It needs to be a min and max length of 6.

```
<input
   type="text"
   class="form-control"
   :class="hasError('vcode') ? 'is-invalid' : ''"
   placeholder="Enter your 6 digit code"
   minlength="6"
   maxlength="6"
   v-model="formData.vcode"
   />
```

The validation isn't working for this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your full code

Comment: or you can compare your code with vue-form-wizard demo code >>  https://binarcode.github.io/vue-form-wizard/#/